# sweep 52 Character private key beginning with L

Tags: private-key, private-key-import, sweep, private-key-format

I'm trying to sweep an unencrypted private key, created with bitaddress.org 4 years ago into, Electrum. I also gave these to family with small amounts on, so need to figure this out before I go down in history as the worst Uncle ever.

The private key is too long and just turns red in the sweep private key box in electrum. I have tried all the versions of the key provided by bitaddress.org but there is a small dollar value when I input the public key in https://www.blockchain.com/explorer

Is there a tool that will convert all bitaddress.org created addresses anywhere? Shall I use a different wallet to sweep the private key?